# How to interpret the Accuracy and Importance in RandomForest test from Cox regression models

Tags: r, random-forest, cox-model

I am trying to use random forest to show the results from Cox regression analysis.

I have 757 samples with complete follow-up data (456 cases and 301 control). The case is defined as `scores` <12, and control was `scores` >=12. The `status` of case is coded as 1, and control is 0.The follow-up time is showed in another variable called `time`. The other variables were `age`, glucose `glu`, interested molecular levels `marker` and the other confounders.

Firstly, I used the survival analysis to find out the most significant model as below:

```
 coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + glu + marker + 
       hdl + smoking + drinking, data=raw)
```

It turns out the `glu` and `marker` has significant interaction:

[image]

the `marker` is significantly higher in the patients than the control if the patients also has high `glu`.

The I use the random forest in two models. One is for `scores`, the other is for `status`:

```
 model1<-randomForest(formula = as.factor(scores) ~ age + glu + 
             marker + hdl + smoking + drinking + time,
             data = raw, importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE, 
             na.action = na.omit) 

 model2<-model1<-randomForest(formula = as.factor(status) ~ age + glu
             + marker + hdl + smoking + drinking + time, 
             data = raw, importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE, 
             na.action = na.omit)
```

The importance of predictors in the two models were like this:

[image]

```
model1: OOB estimate of  error rate: 82.3%
model2: OOB estimate of  error rate: 33.55%
```

I prefer to use model1 because the MeanDecreaseAccuracy is better to be showed in the paper, but its accuracy is only 17.7%. Do you think this accuracy is acceptable? Or the model2 is better?

What is the other suggestion you would give in this case?

I posted this question in the wrong place stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111732/how-to-interperate-the-accuracy-and-importance-in-randomforest-test-from-cox-reg
so I migrated it to cross-validated.

Comment: You didn't migrate, you cross-posted. Migration is achieved by flagging your post on stackoverflow and asking for a moderator to migrate it for you.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I did not know that. Did I do something violating the rule? I am going to read the rules throughly and find out how to do that. Thank you very much for this reminding.

Comment: It's more a request rather than a rule; see the [help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where it mentions cross-posting. If the other one is migrated to here, one or the other will be deleted as a duplicate.